# Apollo Server - how to split queries across multiple files on the server

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

I have just set up Apollo Server according to the [site’s official instructions](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started). However, I find their setup method to be imprudent, because step 3 assumes you’ll only ever have a tiny amount of queries/types - this is from their docs:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  # Comments in GraphQL strings (such as this one) start with the hash (#) symbol.

  # This "Book" type defines the queryable fields for every book in our data source.
  type Book {
    title: String
    author: String
  }

  # The "Query" type is special: it lists all of the available queries that
  # clients can execute, along with the return type for each. In this
  # case, the "books" query returns an array of zero or more Books (defined above).
  type Query {
    books: [Book]
  }
`;
```

If you define `typeDefs` this way, you’ll have to place every single query and type in this single `gql` string in this single file. I want to make it friendlier so that if you had, say, 100 queries, you wouldn’t have to just dump them all in this single query string. However, I can’t seem to find out how to include other queries inside the gql string.

To summarise, I have a schema.ts file:

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-core';

export const typeDefs = gql`
  type Book {
    title: String
    author: String
  }

  type Author {
    name: String
    books: [Book]
  }

  type Query {
    books: [Book]
    authors: [Author]
  }
`;
```

And if I wanted to place `type Author` and `type Book` in separate files, how could I include/reference them in this gql string? For instance, if I had a books.graphql file that includes this:

```
  type Book {
    title: String
    author: String
  }
```

How could it be imported in the typeDefs file and referenced in the `typeDefs` variable?

Also, the .graphql file extension seems to have hardly any documentation anywhere - am I correct in assuming this is only to be used on the client rather than the server? Then the [auto code generator](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com) can generate them into a single file (on the client). I don't even know if the schema should use .ts or .graphql - if anyone has any advice or links to useful reading about it then that would be useful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is **schema merging** from `GraphQL Tools`. Schema merging "consolidates the type definitions and resolvers from many local schema instances into a single executable schema". See more details [here](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/schema-merging).

A quick example:

```
const { mergeTypeDefs } = require('@graphql-tools/merge')

// those are individual schema files
const clientSchema = require('./clientSchema')
const productSchema = require('./productSchema')

const schemas = [clientSchema, productSchema]

// this is the merged schema
const typeDefs = mergeTypeDefs(schemas)
```